# what happens when you draw from Nothing?

Tags: haskell

Generally, what exactly happens when we draw from `Nothing` in a `do` construct?  To illustrate my confusion: why does `do {x <- Just 1; y <- Nothing; return x}` produce `Nothing`?

Comment: In the `Maybe` monad, "nothing comes from nothing". When you chain a bunch of monadic values, as soon as one of them fails (is `Nothing`) the whole chain fails.

Comment: Nothing happens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `do` block is desugared into:

```
Just 1 >>= (\x -> Nothing >>= (\y -> return x))
```

If you look at the [definition of `(>>=)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-665) for Maybe:

```
(Just x) >>= k      = k x
Nothing  >>= _      = Nothing
```

you can see that `Nothing >>= (\y -> return x)` returns `Nothing` and that `Just 1 >>= (\x -> Nothing)` is also `Nothing`.